# Show every convex function is quasiconvex

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, calculus-of-variations

> Show every convex function $f$ is quasiconvex.

A measurable function $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is *quasiconvex* if for every bounded and open $\Omega=(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}, \xi\in\mathbb{R}, \phi \in W_0^{1,\infty}(\Omega,\mathbb{R})$: $$f(\xi)\leq\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int_a^bf(\xi + \phi'(x))dx.$$

I know f is convex if $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda y))\leq \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y), \lambda\in(0,1)$ or also $f(y)\geq f(x)+\beta(y-x)$ with $\beta\in \mathbb{R}$. My first idea was Jensen inequality but I gave up this idea and literally have no other idea how to prove it. Thanks for any help!!

Comment: That's not the definition of “quasiconvex” that I know, compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function .

Comment: @MartinR Regardless of the Wikipedia enry, the posters definition seems to be a common definition in the Calculus of variations, e.g. in Dacorogna, "Direct methods in the Calculus of Variations", Definition in 4.1.1.

Comment: It seems there are different notions of quasiconvexity. In the book of Rockafellar et. altera, Variational Analysis, I found a remark on page 76, according to which Morrey intrroduced a notion of quasiconvexity in a paper in 1952 (#), which seems to agree with the one in this posting, while a different notion ("dating back many decades in game theory and economics") is also in use....
(#) Morrey, C. B. [1952], Quasiconvexity and the lower semicontinuity of multiple integrals,
Pacific Journal of Mathematics, 2, 25–53.

Comment: @PhilSpa a proof of the result you want to show can be found in the book of Dacorogna I mentioned in a previous comment - the proof covers a more general result, though, and is, consequently, a bit involved...

Answer (score 1):

The definition of quasiconvexity which you gave is slightly incorrect. Instead of $\phi \in W^{1,\infty}_0(I,\mathbb{R})$ it should read  $\phi \in W^{1,\infty}_0(\Omega,\mathbb{R})$, keeping all other entities, specifically $\Omega$, defined as before. (**Edit:** the question was edited accordingly after this answer was written...).

With this correction, the claim immediately follows from Jensens inequality, which directly implies (assuming $b>a$)
$$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(\xi+\phi^\prime(x))\, dx\ge f\left(\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b \xi+\phi^\prime(x)\, dx \right) $$
Now note that the right hand side of this inequality is just $f(\xi)$, since $\phi$ has support in $[a,b]$ (if this is not clear to you you may want to start with $\phi\in C^\infty_0((a,b))$ and then approximate the $\phi$ from the general case).

Comment: Thank you! Yes I made an edit in my question referring to $I$ and $\Omega$. Since $\Omega$ is bounded, $W^{1,\infty}_0$ is the space of Lipschitz functions. Suppose $\phi \in C^{\infty}_0$, then $\phi(a)=\phi(b)=0$. Can I argument with partial integration: $\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int^b_a1\cdot\phi'(x)dx = - \frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int^b_a1'\cdot\phi(x)dx= 0$ since $\int_{\partial \Omega}\phi(x)=0$ because of the support of $\phi$? Why is $\phi\in W^{1,\infty}_0$? $C^{\infty}$ is not dense in $W^{1, \infty}$

Comment: @PhilSpa yes you are right. I forgot about $L^{\infty}$ not being separable. It's too long ago - my bad. If partial integration works for you, yes of course. The whole point is that $\int_\Omega \phi^\prime(x) \, dx =0$. If you need further input from me this will have to wait, I'm now busy with other things for a while.